# Use offline authorization in google api upload video to youtube call

Tags: c#, youtube-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I am looking at the .net sample code here : ([Upload a video](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#upload_a_video)) to upload a video to YouTube using C# using the Google Apis .NET library.

The code though redirects you to the google page to get authorization for the call, however I have already done the authorization

```
credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
// This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
// authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
new[] {
    YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload
},
    "user",
CancellationToken.None
```

Can I bypass this authorization and use the code I have already got, the authorization is based on my own YouTube account, not a visitor to the websites YouTube account, and its got offline access type so the token can keep been used over and over again without having to do the authorization each time.

Comment: You have a few options.  1. authenticate it the first time yourself the access will be then stored in a datastore in %appdata%.   Or you could create or own implementation of Idatastore and load your own authentication.